# How to assign values to TextViews in an ArrayList

Tags: arrays, textview

I'm trying to assign calculated values to a series of specific TextViews.

I've defined the TextViews  like this:

```
TextView tvFK6no1,tvFK6no2,tvFK6no3,tvFK6no4,tvFK6no5,tvFK6no6,tvFK6no7,tvFK6no8,tvFK6no9,tvFK6no10,tvFK6no11,tvFK6no12;
```

I've defined the array like this

```
TextView[] tvArrayFK6NO = new TextView[]{tvFK6no1, tvFK6no2, tvFK6no3, tvFK6no4, tvFK6no5, tvFK6no6, tvFK6no7, tvFK6no8, tvFK6no9, tvFK6no10, tvFK6no11, tvFK6no12};
```

and initiated the TextViews like this

```
tvFK6no1 = findViewById(R.id.tvFK6no1);
tvFK6no2 = findViewById(R.id.tvFK6no2);
tvFK6no3 = findViewById(R.id.tvFK6no3);
tvFK6no4 = findViewById(R.id.tvFK6no4);
```

etc

and I'm trying to display data, in this case a variable FK5NO, like this

```
tvArrayFK6NO[i].setText("" + FK6NO);
```

but I keep getting this error message:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

In this case, the FK6NO refers to a number of a star in the Sixth Fundamental Catalog.  I need to list several star numbers(about 10), as well as other data,  in specific TextViews.

I am relatively new to Android Studio and Java.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Before you set the the textview just check its null or not 
if you put some of your code it will be better to understand to any one

Answer (score 0):

duh, this was almost right, but the definition of the TextView[] array needed to go AFTER the findViewByIds of individual TextViews.